# GridView to have Different Controls on same column

Tags: asp.net, gridview

i'm using flowing gridview to bind data

```
  <asp:GridView ID="gvDesign" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="190px" ShowHeader="false">

            <Columns>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Title" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                <ItemTemplate>

                <asp:Label ID="lblText" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Title") %>'></asp:Label>
                 </ItemTemplate>

                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Count" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                <ItemTemplate>

                 <asp:LinkButton ID="lbRevCount" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Count") %>' OnClick="lbRevCount_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
                 </ItemTemplate>


                </asp:TemplateField>

            </Columns>

        </asp:GridView>
```

i need only the first row of the gridView to have the linkbutton.other rows should have a label.currently i'm having linkbutton on all the rows.how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {

        for(int i = 1; i < gvDesign.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            LinkButton lb = gvDesign.Rows[i].FindControl("lbRevCount") as LinkButton;
            if(lb != null)
               lb.Visible = false;
        }
        base.Render(writer);
    }
```

Hope it helps.